# Sync data from SFTP to Google Cloud Storage using LFTP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, synchronization, google-cloud-storage, sftp, lftp

I'm sync data from sftp server to GCS using lftp on a compute instance. I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@agarwalsh?source=follow_footer--------------------------follow_footer-) link to establish my connection.

I ran my cron job to be scheduled at some specific time but i'm getting nothing on my mounted cloud bucket which means my cron job is failing but I don't know the reason. where can i see the status of my cron job? I have used following command for cron job

```
45 15 * * * lftp sftp://<username>:<password>@<sftp-server-ip/domain>  -e "set sftp:auto-confirm yes;  mirror --verbose /path/on/sftp ~/gcsBucket ;  bye"
```

This job is scheduled at 3:45pm every day.
Did I make a mistake in the above command?

Comment: Are you sure that your gcsfuse mount point is correctly mounted and accessible by the user that is used by the cron job?

Comment: i'm using my default project in google cloud ...it has all the firewall access ...do I have to add something else??...

Comment: My concern is Linux environment and not GCP environment here. Add this to your crontab `* * * * * whoami > /tmp/whoami`. The content of the file will provide you the user used in the cron execution context. Then perform a `sudo su - <user in whoami>` and try to reach your fuse mounting point. It's maybe a problem of linux ACL.

Comment: What is the output of cron log /var/log/cron.log ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Solution that worked for me was:

1. Make sure you are NOT a root user.
2. Mount the GCS bucket successfully, Every time you restart the machine, you need to
   remount. Configure remounting script as a startup script can be a
   good approach.
3. Make sure your Storage API is enabled in project.
4. **Edit your VM and under API access scopes, enable Storage API for
   a full or read/write access. Depends on your case of usage.**

Point 4 is important as it is nowhere mentioned in any docs, I figured it out by hit and try.
Congratulations. You are good to test your SFTP sync utility